# Image becomes empty when uploading from JSON using POSTMAN

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

- I am trying to upload an image from JSON code.
  But when it is uploaded its data is stored in the folder. But data is lost(the file exist but has 0 bytes) I don't know if the problem is exactly from where. If anyone know please help me.

This is the code

```
 public function decodeImage($imageData)
   { 
    $imageData = $dat->imageData;
    $this->decodeImage($imageData); 
    $filename = "sampletest";
    $binary=base64_decode($imageData);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    $file = fopen('./'.$filename, 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    }
```

Comment: It is made recursive function out there: `decodeImage($arg)` is called inside `decodeImage($arg)`. Probably there is some mess.

Comment: I suggest checking to see what `base64_decode($imageData);` returns. It returns `FALSE` on failure which is probably an invalid argument to fwrite.

Comment: @DFriend  i given imageData input like "/9j/4AAQSkZJRg....."but base64_decode($imageData); it returns that same value "=base64_decode(/9j/4AAQSkZJR....." i think it is not at all decoding my value.can u tell me wat abt ur opinion? am the newbie for this, so I can't found exactly  where is my mistake

Comment: The issue is that the file has no content (exists but 0 bytes), right? So you have to make sure `$binary` has something in it. `$binary` could be equal to `FALSE` because `base64_decode(...` might return `FALSE`. You would not want to write to a file in that case. In short, make sure `$binary` is not equal to `FALSE` before calling `fwrite(...`.

Comment: Also, remove the line `header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');` it has noting to do with what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: What does `$this->decodeImage($imageData);` accomplish? You realize that this is a recursive call to the function you are in right?